# How to guess the number of inflection points?

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find fast the number of possible inflection points of:
$$y=(x-1)(x-2)^2(x-3)^4(x-4)^3$$

I know if the degree of any polynomial is even, its plot starts from the 2th quadrant to 1st quadrant of $\mathbb R^2$. This was what I could do **fast**. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The term $(x-3)^4$ does not produce an inflection point at $3$, so there are no more than $6$. I would guess $6$.  But it is certainly not a fully verified guess.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Yes. x=3 is just a root for y. 6?

Comment: If you think about the product rule, $x=3$ is a double root of the second derivative. But there is no inflection oint at $x=3$. (Think $x^4$, it does not change concavity at $0$.) So two "possible" inflection points are missing.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Can we say for these kind of functions, there is exactly one extreme between two consecutive roots? Thanks.

Comment: There is at least one, but there could be more than one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just imagine what the graph looks like.  It starts above the $x$-axis, crosses below at $x=1$, is tangent to the $x$-axis at $x=2$ and $x=3$, and then crosses above at $x=4$, with an inflection point at $(4,0)$.  Thinking about the shape, I count:

- One inflection point between $x=1$ and $x=2$,
- Two inflection points between $x=2$ and $x=3$,
- Two inflection points between $x=3$ and $x=4$, and
- One inflection point at $x=4$.

Thus there are six inflection points.  This makes sense -- the second derivative should have eight zeroes, but two of them are at $x=3$, leaving six inflection points.

Comment: Oh yes. I see it now. Thanks Jim Thanks @André.